# what is home_url() equivalent in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am studying Wordpress with some ajax function. My problem is the PATH in my request is in hardcoded is there any function for this? And I can't get the root folder in my site.

Here's my code and it returns an error because my path is incomplete:

```
$.post(document.location.protocol + '//' + document.location.host + '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', {action: 'zwap_add_wishlist', postId: 100}, function(response){
    alert(response);
});
```

And I got this URL:

```
http://localhost/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
```

My problem is my wordpress is in this URL:

```
http://localhost/wp/wordpress_tutorial/
```

I know the function ajaxurl() but I can't apply it because my file is in javascript

Answer (score 1):

These should do it.

```js
var base_url = window.location.origin;

var host = window.location.host;

var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
```

**or this**

```js
var getUrl = window.location;
var baseUrl = getUrl .protocol + "//" + getUrl.host + "/" + getUrl.pathname.split('/')[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

A global variable ajaxurl is defined in the admin header to be used in ajax call since WP 2.8.

For more information: http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: yes correct but how can I call it in a javascript file?

Comment: $.post(ajaxurl, {action: 'zwap_add_wishlist', postId: 100}, function(response){
    alert(response);
});

Answer (score 1):

just use inbuild functionality

add_action( 'init', 'my_script_enqueuer' );

```
function my_script_enqueuer() {

   wp_localize_script( 'my_voter_script', 'myAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));        

   wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );

}
```

then your url will available in `myAjax.ajaxurl`

and you can use

```
$.post(myAjax.ajaxurl, {action: 'zwap_add_wishlist', postId: 100}, function(response){
    alert(response);
});
```

try this and let me know if it is working
here is the refrence [refrence](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/)